# Why is Meshlab identifying self-intersecting faces incorrectly?

Tags: mesh, surface, meshlab, self-intersection

[meshlab](/questions/tagged/meshlab) occassionally finds spurious self-intersections that don't seem to be correct - see this minimal example of just [two faces](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lg00B9hx0abekV-F4TUg8ogU70T2Cd6r). [meshlab](/questions/tagged/meshlab) identifies the faces as self-intersecting. If I save the file as an ascii [stl](/questions/tagged/stl), the file no longer shows to be self-intersecting.

I've checked the binary content of the binary file to see if there are non-displayed triangles in case zero-area triangles are simply not shown but there don't seem to be.

Comment: How exactly did your MeshLab identify them as self intersecting? I downloaded your example, opened it with MeshLab v1.3.2 and chose
`Filters > Cleaning and Repairing > Select Self Intersecting Faces` but despite clicking "Apply" they did not get marked.

Comment: @Dominik Mokriš I am using MeshLab 64bit fp v2016.12 and I use Filters->Selection->Select Self Intersecting Faces. Just downloaded and tested again to confirm both faces are selected even though they very clearly shouldn't be.

Comment: @Dominik Mokriš, learnt how to use that filter from your comment. Cheers!